# CALayer mask removing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I know a mask is added with something like

```
UIImageView *mask = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mask.png"]];
[mask setFrame:kHexagonMaskRect];
[self setBackgroundColor:kBackgroundColor];
[self layer].mask = [mask layer];
[mask release];
```

But how do I remove it? Setting it to nil works, but that is leaking.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

**Add mask**

```
UIImageView *maskimageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mask.png"]];
CALayer *mask = [CALayer layer];
mask.contents = (id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"mask.png"] CGImage];
maskimageview.layer.mask = mask;
maskimageview.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

**Remove mask**

```
 maskimageview.layer.mask = nil;
```

Hope, this will help you..

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.  maskimageview.layer.mask = nil; will not leak?

Comment: No it won't - you're assigning a property here, not a simple member. As a property layer.mask will take care of releasing previous data.

Comment: Sometimes it requires maskimageview.layer.masksToBounds = NO; too